# Best Way To Recurse Through Registry (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

So long story short, I'm trying to create a diff of two registry hives located in binary .dat files.

After mounting the hives using the RegLoadAppKey, what is the best way to recurse through all keys and their values?

I looked at RegEnumKeyEx, but that only allows me to iterate through the sub keys of the root node returned by RegLoadAppKey and doesn't (as far as I know) return any sort of handle to the sub keys.

Also the reason I am using RegLoadAppKey is because this mini app needs be able to be run without admin privileges.

Comment: You [can use WinDiff](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171780) if that helps (and it's a one-off).

Comment: I'd probably just do export from regedit and use a regular text differ

Answer (score 2):

Not to be a wet blanket

From the MSDN docs on RegLoadAppKey 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724886(v=vs.85).aspx

> Unlike RegLoadKey, RegLoadAppKey does not load the hive under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_USERS. Instead, the hive is loaded under a
>   *special root that cannot be enumerated*. As a result, *there is no way to enumerate hives currently loaded by RegLoadAppKey*

In addition, you might run into roadblocks over some of the security settings you are trying to avoid

> All keys inside the hive must have the same security descriptor,
>   otherwise the function will fail. This security descriptor must grant
>   the caller the access specified by the samDesired parameter or the
>   function will fail. You cannot use the RegSetKeySecurity function on
>   any key inside the hive.

Comment: So in the RegLoadAppKey documentation I read the following:  "All operations on hives loaded by RegLoadAppKey have to be performed relative to the handle return in phkResult."  So I think it should definitely be possible.  The second comment about the security descriptor does have me worried though...

Comment: I thought this means you can't enumerate the mount point, not the keys in the mounted hive?